# ASP.NET CustomError 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, custom-error-pages

So I have basically setup a customError in the web.config which works fine when an exception occurs in the webservice, but now I want to add another customError which will look for an http 404 error. When the webservice gets an exception the ErrorPage.aspx CustomError works fine and when I enter an invalid URL the Yellow Screen Of Death comes up which I don't want, I want the 404.aspx error to come up.

Here is my code for the web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/ErrorPage.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

This is the URL that returns when I type in the wrong URL

```
http://localhost:28745/ErrorPages/404.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/Accounfghogin.aspx
```

And this is the Yellow Screen Of Death I get when typing in the wrong URL

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

Comment: It looks as though the Url that returns is correct; have you created the `404.aspx` page in your project?

Comment: Yes I have its in the ErrorPages folder where ErrorPage.aspx is (This Custom error works but only for webservice exceptions but does not work when I type the incorrect URL in)

Comment: Can you post the yellow screen of death screen shot

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you try replacing the tildes (~) with the full path to the file?

Comment: I tried that already. Which I don't think that is the problem cause the ErrorPage.aspx works for exception that occur on the webservice and that is in the same directory as the 404.aspx. The thing I don't understand is that the ErrorPage.aspx works for exceptions and even when i take out <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/404.aspx /> The ErrorPage.aspx shows up when i type in the wrong URL. But when i put in the <error> tag the yellow screen of death comes up saying <customErrors mode="Off"> etc...

Comment: Can you post the details of what the yellow screen says?